# Finding Data in SAS Output for Linear Regression

Tags: regression, t-test, sas

How does SAS calculate t-values?

For example, say we have two variables: intercept (which is always present) and temperature in a model that is regressing temperature on mortality in a certain region.

t Value

-1.39 (Intercept)

```
(B)  (Temperature)
```

How might one calculate (B)?  I understand that symbolically if temperature is taken to be $b_1$ then we have $\frac{b_1- \beta_1}{s({b_1})}$.  I assume they are testing here whether or not $\beta = 0$ so we can make the numerator just $b_1$. Where might one look in a typical SAS output to get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most SAS regression procedures, the t value is part of the ParameterEstimates table.
For the GLM procedure, see this [example in the PROC GLM documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glm_sect006.htm).
(If you have a classification variable in the analysis, be sure to add the SOLUTION option on the MODEL statement in order to product the ParameterEstimates table.)
For the REG procedure, see this [example in the PROC REG documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect003.htm).

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I do see it listed in SAS output but I suppose I'm asking at a more basic statistical level how does one calculate the t-value?  Which other values given in the normal SAS output come together to make that number?  It is more for my review of the concept.

Comment: The formulas used by the SAS regression procedures are included in the documentation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_introreg_sect009.htm